# Convert RDD to Dataframe in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

The RDD has been created in the format `Array[Array[String]]` and has the following values:

```
val rdd : Array[Array[String]] = Array(
Array("4580056797", "0", "2015-07-29 10:38:42", "0", "1", "1"), 
Array("4580056797", "0", "2015-07-29 10:38:43", "0", "1", "1"))
```

I want to create a dataFrame with the schema :

```
val schemaString = "callId oCallId callTime duration calltype swId"
```

Next steps:

```
scala> val rowRDD = rdd.map(p => Array(p(0), p(1), p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5).trim))
rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[14] at map at <console>:39
scala> val calDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

Gives the following error:

```
console:45: error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:
     (rdd: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
    (rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_],beanClass: Class[_])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
    (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
    (rowRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]],   
    org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
       val calDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just paste into a `spark-shell`:

```
val a = 
  Array(
    Array("4580056797", "0", "2015-07-29 10:38:42", "0", "1", "1"), 
    Array("4580056797", "0", "2015-07-29 10:38:42", "0", "1", "1"))

val rdd = sc.makeRDD(a)

case class X(callId: String, oCallId: String, 
  callTime: String, duration: String, calltype: String, swId: String)
```

Then `map()` over the RDD to create instances of the case class, and then create the DataFrame using `toDF()`:

```
scala> val df = rdd.map { 
  case Array(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5) => X(s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5) }.toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = 
  [callId: string, oCallId: string, callTime: string, 
    duration: string, calltype: string, swId: string]
```

This infers the schema from the case class.

Then you can proceed with:

```
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- callId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- oCallId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- callTime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- duration: string (nullable = true)
 |-- calltype: string (nullable = true)
 |-- swId: string (nullable = true)

scala> df.show()
+----------+-------+-------------------+--------+--------+----+
|    callId|oCallId|           callTime|duration|calltype|swId|
+----------+-------+-------------------+--------+--------+----+
|4580056797|      0|2015-07-29 10:38:42|       0|       1|   1|
|4580056797|      0|2015-07-29 10:38:42|       0|       1|   1|
+----------+-------+-------------------+--------+--------+----+
```

If you want to use `toDF()` in a normal program (not in the `spark-shell`), make sure (quoted from [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Spark-Scala-Error-value-toDF-is-not-a-member-of-org-apache-spark/td-p/29878)):

- To `import sqlContext.implicits._` right after creating the `SQLContext`
- Define the case class outside of the method using `toDF()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert first you `Array` into `Row` and then define schema. I made assumption that most of your fields are `Long`

```
    val rdd: RDD[Array[String]] = ???
    val rows: RDD[Row] = rdd map {
      case Array(callId, oCallId, callTime, duration, swId) =>
        Row(callId.toLong, oCallId.toLong, callTime, duration.toLong, swId.toLong)
    }

    object schema {
      val callId = StructField("callId", LongType)
      val oCallId = StructField("oCallId", StringType)
      val callTime = StructField("callTime", StringType)
      val duration = StructField("duration", LongType)
      val swId = StructField("swId", LongType)

      val struct = StructType(Array(callId, oCallId, callTime, duration, swId))
    }

    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema.struct)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `spark 1.6.1` and `scala 2.10`

I got the same error `error: overloaded method value createDataFrame with alternatives:`

For me, gotcha was the signature in `createDataFrame`, I was trying to use the `val rdd : List[Row]`, but it failed
 because `java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` and `scala.collection.immutable.List[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` are NOT the same.

The working solution I've found is I would convert `val rdd : Array[Array[String]]` into `RDD[Row]` via `List[Array[String]]`. I find this is the closest to what's in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/sql-programming-guide.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val rdd_original : Array[Array[String]] = Array(
    Array("4580056797", "0", "2015-07-29 10:38:42", "0", "1", "1"), 
    Array("4580056797", "0", "2015-07-29 10:38:42", "0", "1", "1"))

val rdd : List[Array[String]] = rdd_original.toList

val schemaString = "callId oCallId callTime duration calltype swId"

// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))

// Convert records of the RDD to Rows.
val rowRDD = rdd.map(p => Row(p: _*)) // using splat is easier
// val rowRDD = rdd.map(p => Row(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3), p(4), p(5))) // this also works

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize(rowRDD:List[Row]), schema)
df.show
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `schema` is, like in the [Spark Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html), as follow:

```
val schema =
  StructType(
    schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
```

If you look at the signature of the [createDataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext), here is the one that accepts a StructType as 2nd argument (for Scala)

> def createDataFrame(rowRDD: RDD[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
>
> Creates a DataFrame from an RDD containing Rows using the given
>   schema.

So it accepts as 1st argument a `RDD[Row]`. What you have in `rowRDD` is a `RDD[Array[String]]` so there is a mismatch.

Do you need an `RDD[Array[String]]` ?

Otherwise you can use the following to create your dataframe:

```
val rowRDD = rdd.map(p => Row(p(0), p(1), p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5).trim))
```

Comment: What if one of the p elements have null values in the RDD and I need to do a toInt before converting to Row type :
val rowRDD = rdd.map(p => Row(p(0), p(1).toInt, p(2), p(3).toFloat, p(4), p(5).trim))
But both p(1) and p(3) have null values in the original raw rdd. This is failing so i was forced to remove the toInt and toFloat but that doesnt help as my schema defn needs to have int and float.