# Convert an org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector RDD to a DataFrame in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector RDD that [Int Int Int] .
I am trying to convert this into a dataframe using this code

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayData
```

vectrdd belongs to the type org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector

```
val vectarr = vectrdd.toArray()
case class RFM(Recency: Integer, Frequency: Integer, Monetary: Integer)
val df = vectarr.map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => RFM(p0, p1, p2) }.toDF()
```

I am getting the following error

```
warning: fruitless type test: a value of type         
org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector cannot also be a Array[T]
val df = vectarr.map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => RFM(p0, p1, p2) }.toDF()

error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
found   : Array[T]
required: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
val df = vectarr.map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => RFM(p0, p1, p2) }.toDF()
```

The second method i tried is this

```
val vectarr=vectrdd.toArray().take(2)
case class RFM(Recency: String, Frequency: String, Monetary: String)
val df = vectrdd.map { case (t0, t1, t2) => RFM(p0, p1, p2) }.toDF()
```

I got this error

```
error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
found   : (T1, T2, T3)
required: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
val df = vectrdd.map { case (t0, t1, t2) => RFM(p0, p1, p2) }.toDF()
```

I used this example as a guide >> 
[Convert RDD to Dataframe in Spark/Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127970/convert-rdd-to-dataframe-in-spark-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vectarr` will have type of `Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]`, so in the pattern matching you cannot match `Array(p0, p1, p2)` because what is being matched is a Vector, not Array.

Also, you should not do `val vectarr = vectrdd.toArray()` - this will convert the RDD to Array and then the final call to `toDF` will not work, since `toDF` only works on RDD's.

The correct line would be (provided you change `RFM` to have Doubles)

```
val df = vectrdd.map(_.toArray).map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => RFM(p0, p1, p2)}.toDF()
```

or, equivalently, replace `val vectarr = vectrdd.toArray()` (which produces `Array[Vector]`)   with `val arrayRDD = vectrdd.map(_.toArray())`  (producing `RDD[Array[Double]]`)