# org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector to DataFrame scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have an output like the following

```
val output = Vectors.dense(Vectors.dense(pred.toDouble).toArray ++ predProb.toArray)
output: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector = [0.0,0.9279938116118619,0.07200618838813808]
```

I want to convert that into a DataFrame with the following as column values

```
case class Prob(Pred: Double, NoProb: Double, YesProb: Double)
```

Can somebody please help.

Thanks

Bala

Answer (score 0):

val df = output.map(_.toArray).map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => Prob(p0, p1, p2)}.toDF()

Comment: you can have more détails in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688258/convert-an-org-apache-spark-mllib-linalg-vector-rdd-to-a-dataframe-in-spark-usin

Comment: Thanks @yahoo. However this is what i get if i do that.

   scala> val df = output.map(_.toArray).map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => Prob(p0, p1, p2)}.toDF()
<console>:44: error: value map is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
         val df = output.map(_.toArray).map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => Prob(p0, p1, p2)}.toDF()

Comment: actually , you can convert toArray without map just put this :
output.toArray.map { case Array(p0, p1, p2) => Prob(p0, p1, p2)}.toDF()

Comment: thanks again @yahoo.. i get a different error now..

scala> output.toArray.map{case Array(p0,p1,p2) => Prob(p0,p1,p2)}.toDF()
<console>:45: error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
 found   : Array[T]
 required: Double
              output.toArray.map{case Array(p0,p1,p2) => Prob(p0,p1,p2)}.toDF()

Comment: i am using spark 1.6.1 and Scala 2.10